# Accessing Array in a class

Tags: c++, class

I'm still new to C++ and working out this assignment.

When I attempt to call the various functions, I'm informed that "bank isn't defined."

```
class bankAccount {
    private:
        float bank[10];
    public:
        void deposit (int num, float value);
        void balance (int num);
        void withdraw (int num, float value);
        void transfer (int num1, int num2, int value);
}; // end class

void deposit (int num, float value){
    bank[num] += value;
}
```

bankAccount.h:16:37: error: 'bank' was not declared in this scope

Comment: deposit function isn't part of bankAccount interface and can't have access to it's private members. Moreover it doen't have even object of bankAccount class to even try access to bank array.
To sum up, u're trying to access the variable in wrong scope(u're using it in score of global defined function deposit(int,float) while float bank[] is in score of bankAccount class

Answer (score 4):

```
void deposit (int num, float value){
    bank[num] += value;
}
```

defines a free function.

You need

```
void bankAccount::deposit (int num, float value){
    bank[num] += value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`void deposit(int num, float value)` is a free function, however :

```
void bankAccount::deposit (int num, float value){
    bank[num] += value;
}
```

Is the definition of the member function.